# How to put multiple Rows inside one Row in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to put two list inside of one Row widget.
What the code is like:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(child: ListView(children: [TabItem(), TabItem()])),
    Row(children: [TextButton(), IconButton()]),
  ],
)
```

I found that I cannot wrap both of list in `Expanded` or `Flexible`, because these two widgets will split the sapce in half, or they will split the space by percentage.

For the left list, I want it to be scrollable and flexible, like in CSS `flex: auto` did.

For the right list, I want to put some buttons in it, like in CSS `flex: 0 0 auto` did.

Comment: what is wrong with it ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with your code.
Just don't forget to set width to IconButton since the IconButton not wrapped by any widget that defines its width.

You need to define width of Row Container.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: MyWidget(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width:100,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: ListView(children: [
              Container(height:100,color:Colors.blue), 
            Container(height:100,color:Colors.blue),
            Container(height:100,color:Colors.blue),
            Container(height:100,color:Colors.blue)])),
            Row(children: [Text("1"), Text("2")]),
          ],),
      ),
    );
  }
}`
```